# iTunes will not add some mp3 files

Tags: macos, itunes

I own several albums from the same band and want to import all of the .mp3 files into iTunes (v. 12.0.1.26). However, iTunes will not add a few songs from 3 of the albums. All of the other songs were imported without a problem except for these few.

I have tried using "Automatically Add to iTunes" in Finder as well as "Add to Library..." in iTunes for these files. When attempting the former, the files are placed in the "Not Added" sub-folder. With the latter, nothing happens (I check by going to My Music => Songs and sort by Date Added to see if any new files show up regardless of expected ID3 information).

The problem files play normally with Quicktime and VLC player.

My Mac is caught up on all software updates.

Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: Are you sure the files were not already present somehow?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the files are not present anywhere in iTunes.

Comment: Having same problem, with last version: 12.3.1.23 on Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

You can try to fix your mp3 file, there are some great software for that.

> MP3val is a small, high-speed, free software tool for checking MPEG
>   audio files' integrity. It can be useful for finding corrupted files
>   (e.g. incompletely downloaded, truncated, containing garbage). MP3val
>   is also able to fix most of the problems. Being a multiplatform
>   application, MP3val can be runned both under Windows and under Linux
>   (or BSD).

**Src :** http://mp3val.sourceforge.net

I don't really know if it's because your mp3 files are broken, but it's possible. Perhaps QuickTime and VLC are more permissive than iTunes...

Answer (score 0):

This may result in a small loss of audio quality, but unlikely sufficient to notice

Get [XLD](http://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html) (free/donationware)

The interface of this app is a little strange, but works very well.

- Open the Prefs & set the Output format to WAV. You can leave everything else as it is.
- Drop your mp3 files onto XLD's Dock icon. [that's the bit that's not obvious]
- Click OK in the popup window.

Once completed, reverse the process by setting XLD to output as LAME MP3 [or iTunes likes MPEG4-AAC format too; your choice]