# Mp3 file sounds fine in some media players but not others

Tags: itunes, audio, mp3

I have a number of mp3 files that I encoded via LAME from the original super nes sound files. They sound fine in the following:

- Windows Media Player
- Foobar2000 (windows)
- VLC (all platforms)
- Clementine (linux)
- doubleTwist cloud player (android)

But there are constant sound flubs in itunes in sierra (as well as the last umpteen versions of itunes dating back to mavericks (when I first had this problem) *as well as* doubletwist on mac.

As I am primarily a Mac user, I would *really* like to get these sounding correct in iTunes rather than use VLC et al. All I found about it was [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159790/itunes-will-not-add-some-mp3-files). Does anyone know why this would be the case?

I've used mediaInfo to look at a good and 'bad' mp3:

*Good* (plays in all players on all platforms):

```
Dragon Quest VI Another World
MPEG Audio
Overall bit rate mode: variable
Overall bit rate: 130kbps
32.0 kHz
2chan MPEG version 1 layer 3
```

*Bad*

```
Final Fantasy V Ahead on our Way
Overall bit rate mode: variable
Overall bit rate: 210 kbps
32.0 kHz
2chan MPEG version 1 layer 3
```

Comment: Try something like [MediaInfo Mac](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Mac_OS) old version is free, newest is 99¢ & see if you can spot a difference in the encoding in ones that work & ones that don't

Comment: I'll check it out, but just to make sure I was clear in my question, its not that some of the sound files work and some don't, its that the *same* files work in one media player (eg VLC) but not in others (eg iTunes, doubleTwist).

Comment: Sure - I understood that. I meant to check ones that work everywhere against ones that are more picky. or… are they all glitchy in iTunes etc. if so, check against something that isn't [of course] or… edit 2… throw them at me over dropbox or something & I'll have a go here

Comment: How exactly did you encode them (bps, variable etc)?

Comment: Edited my post, let me know if you need the actual files. @patrix variable, since the original files were meant for minimal footprint on decades-old hardware it never occured to me that sound quality would be any kind of issue, mp3 is a compressed format but the original .scp file for the entire album is smaller than the mp3 for 1 track. Also sorry I apparently undid your formatting edits, I must have edited right about the same time as you. Thank you for fixing it (again)

Comment: eek - I've never heard of .scp as an audio format - not sure if I've got anything that can handle it. Can't even find any real ref on Google for them

Comment: Super nintendo soundfiles. Foobar2000 (windows) can handle (and with a LAME plugin, convert) them. I know its rather obscure.